# XSLT output to HTML: add an HTML element with incremented number, based on another element

Tags: xslt, tei

I have `tei:xml` documents which I am transforming into HTML with XSLT 2.0. The effective structure of the tei documents look like this:

```
...
<p xml:lang="LA">
  <seg type="a" corresp="#fooid"><date type="doc_date" when="1245"/>In non hendrerit metus. Sed in 
       posuere eros, sit amet pharetra lacus.</seg>
  <seg type="a">Nullam semper varius justo, vitae mollis turpis 
       dapibus sit amet. Donec<note type="public_note"></note> 
       rhoncus tempor urna sit amet 
       imperdiet.</seg>
  <seg type="a">Integer id ante nunc. Curabitur at ligula sed 
       arcu consequat gravida et id orci. Morbi quis porta 
       dolor.</seg>
  <seg type="a" corresp="#fooid2">Sed dictum<note type="public_note"> 
       sem nec urna sodales cursus. Donec sit amet nibh tempor, 
       congue ligula semper, rhoncus odio.</seg>
<p>
...
```

In several  `<xsl:template>`s I transform the xml to HTML and thencycle through the tei document to identify elements that need to be transformed into superscript footnote numbers. I use the `<xsl:number function>` to increment the number:

```
 <xsl:template match="p">
   <div><xsl:apply-templates></div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="seg[@type='a']">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="seg//date[@type='doc_date'] | 
   seg//note[@type='public_note']">
     <sup>
       <xsl:number count="seg//date[@type='doc_date'] | 
          seg//note[@type='public_note']" format="1" level="any"/>
     </sup>
 </xsl:template>
```

Producing three `<sup/>` with incremental values 1, 2, 3:

```
<div>
   <p><sup>1</sup>In non hendrerit metus. Sed in 
       posuere eros, sit amet pharetra lacus.</p>
   <p>Nullam semper varius justo, vitae mollis turpis 
       dapibus sit amet. Donec<sup>2</sup> rhoncus tempor 
       urna sit amet imperdiet.</p>
   <p>Integer id ante nunc. Curabitur at ligula sed 
       arcu consequat gravida et id orci. Morbi quis porta 
       dolor.</p>
   <p>Sed dictum sem<sup>3</sup> nec urna sodales cursus. 
      Donec sit amet nibh tempor, congue ligula semper, 
      rhoncus odio.</p>
<div>
```

The problem that I can't seem to solve is how to output the following, where `<sup>` is added AFTER `<p>` (based on `<tei:seg>`) when the 
condition `seg[@corresp]` is met:

```
<div>
   <p><sup>1</sup>In non hendrerit metus. Sed in 
       posuere eros, sit amet pharetra lacus.</p><sup>2</sup>
   <p>Nullam semper varius justo, vitae mollis turpis 
       dapibus sit amet. Donec<sup>3</sup> rhoncus tempor 
       urna sit amet imperdiet.</p>
   <p>Integer id ante nunc. Curabitur at ligula sed 
       arcu consequat gravida et id orci. Morbi quis porta 
       dolor.</p>
   <p>Sed dictum sem<sup>4</sup> nec urna sodales cursus. 
      Donec sit amet nibh tempor, congue ligula semper, 
      rhoncus odio.</p><sup>5</sup>
<div>
```

I can get them to work in separate templates (while creating the html `<p/>`), but not in one template.  However, being in separate templates restarts the numbering.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a template in a different mode to create number and include the `seg[@corresp]` elements in the pattern (as I have done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUb) but as `xsl:number` works based on the position of nodes in the source document you don't get the order you have indicated as basically the `seg[@corresp]` elements that way are numbered with lower numbers as their child or descendant `date` or `note` elements.

So basically I think you need to run a two step transformation, add a `note` or `date` or other marker element at the end of the `seg[@corresp]`, then number them and the `note`/`date` in a second step:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode name="add-marker" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="seg[@corresp]" mode="add-marker">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <marker/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="markers-added">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-marker"/>
  </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$markers-added/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
   <div><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="seg[@type='a']">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="seg//date[@type='doc_date'] | 
   seg//note[@type='public_note'] | marker">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="number">
     <sup>
        <xsl:number count="marker | seg//date[@type='doc_date'] | 
          seg//note[@type='public_note']" format="1" level="any"/>         
     </sup>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUb/1

I have used the XSLT 3 `xsl:mode` declaration in there but it could be replaced by the identity transformation template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="add-marker">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

for an XSLT 2 processor.

Comment: I understand this in principle, although I still struggle with the order of operations using modes. I currently have a number of other (simple) transformations acting on the same document, and I don't want to muck up everything else by introducing this. In your scenario, does `@mode="add-marker"` effectively fire off before all other transformations? Also, do I need to be concerned about namespace and schema problems by injecting `<marker/>`? Thanks very much.

Comment: The mode alone does not fire off anything but I have declared a global variable `xsl:variable name="markers-added"` where that mode is used and then, in the template of the default/unnamed mode for the document node `xsl:template match="/"` I push the variable's child nodes to the other (i.e. your existing templates plus my suggestions) templates which basically means the XSLT processor first builds the variable contents with the named mode and then processes the variable's value with the unnamed mode.

Comment: As for namespaces, yes, if your original content is in a namespace and your existing XSLT code uses `xpath-default-namespace` for that namespace to work with your shown patterns (e.g. `seg//date[@type='doc_date']`) then I think you need to make sure you put the `marker` element in the same namespace as your original input with e.g. hard-coding `<marker xmlns="http://example.com"/>` or by using `<xsl:element name="marker" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>` to copy it from the `seg` element.

Comment: I've tried to integrate this into existing XSLT, but the processor (Saxon) is telling me there is ambiguity, because I now have two templates addressing `<xsl:template match="/">` I use this template to build the HTML "frame" from the document root node. The processor has clearly chosen my original template over the second one I've introduced as your proposed transformation doesn't occur.

Comment: You will need to show me the original template in an edit to the question or in a new question to address that properly, if your existing template builds a HTML document structure at some point I guess you use `apply-templates` to delegate processing of the input node to your other templates and there you would now need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$markers-added/node()"/>` instead, as that is your original input with the `marker` elements added.

Comment: I've posted a follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860271/xslt-2-0-creating-incremental-footnote-numbers-in-html-output-through-multi-stag with all the gory details. I'll mark this one as answered.

Comment: I've added a bounty of 50 to this question which will be given to you once Stackoverflow releases it. It's in recognition for helping me in great detail with numerous problems I had in constructing this stylesheet.