# XSLT 2.0 moving a node (created in first step of a multi-step transformation)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, tei

XML and the XSLT 2.0 files for this question are found at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwX/3

I am trying to 'move' an element ahead of outputting a section of HTML. This element was created during [the first part of the transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860271/xslt-2-0-creating-incremental-footnote-numbers-in-html-output-through-multi-stag)) using  `@mode` to insert footnote numbers into the text. The first mode `fn-add-marker` creates `<fn-marker/>` to hold the footnote number. The second mode `number` then inserts incremented footnote numbers. All of this works fine (through to line 52 and then after 68 in the XSLT fiddle).

Now I need to 'move' an element into the sibling element that spawned it  in the mode above. I've combined this with the HTML output: the final idea is that element `<tei:seg>` is transformed into HTML `<p>` such that this :

```
<seg type="dep_event">text</seg><fn-marker>incremented no.</fn-marker>
```

Now becomes this HTML (where `seg` = `p`, and `fn-marker` = `sup`:

```
<p>text<sup>incremented no.</sup></p>
```

ie. where a condition is met, the footnote is brought inside a sibling element to be contained in `<p>`.

The code I inserted (below) works for 3 of 4 needed steps to accomplish this move. It seems the code associated with step 3 does not locate a value in `<fn-marker/>`. But if I remove all this, the value is in fact there! It makes me think this is a problem of modes.

The code below does this:

1. output each instance of `<tei:seg @type="dep_event>"` into a `<p>` **works**
2. create the `<sup>`inside the `<seg>` that meets the sibling condition **works**
3. copy the text() content of `<fn-marker>` into the `<sup>` that meets the sibling condition  **does not work**
4. destroy the old `<fn-marker>1</fn-marker>` **works**

Referring to line numbers at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwX/3:

line 56-63:

```
 <xsl:template match="tei:seg[@type='dep_event']">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:fn-marker]">
            <!-- next line of code does not find a value in /text() -->
            <sup><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:fn-marker/]text()"/></sup>
        </xsl:if>
    </p>
 </xsl:template>
```

line 66:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:fn-marker[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:seg[@type='dep_event']]]"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The original problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856229/xslt-output-to-html-add-an-html-element-with-incremented-number-based-on-anoth asked to put the `sup` element after the `p` the `tei:seg` was transformed to. If the `sup` belongs into the `p`, can't you just put the marker there directly, like done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqT/11, and that way avoid the problem to add another step to move it?

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to work through merging two separate processes from a previous activity into this one transformation and `modes` are something I'm still trying to get my head around in merging them. I'm still on training wheels. I thought I would take baby-steps through this learning curve, but it's going to take time for me to understand what you've done. It's brillant and I can't thank you enough for getting me through the toughest part of this transformation.

Comment: @Martin Honnen As you've helped me a lot with this problem, I'm happy to put a bounty on this question (when allowed) and if you post up a simple response I'll accept that. Thanks again.