# XSLT 2.0 - xsl:number inconsistent number order

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, tei

In XSLT 2.0 I am processing tei:xml documents to HTML. During this process I output footnote numbers in two passes, for two reasons.

First, adding numbers in the text body itself by selecting certain elements to which are attached/replaced by `<sup>` (for superscript numbers).

Second, in the footer `div` I create a list of those same footnote numbers with various notes.

All of this works great, thanks in large part to the help received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874845/xslt-2-0-moving-a-node-created-in-first-step-of-a-multi-step-transformation) on SO.

But during testing through the hundreds of documents, I noticed a problem of number order.

The first step outputs the numbers in the **correct order** (lines 9-45). The second step outputs the elements in the **wrong order** (lines 73-99). XSLT fiddle here demonstrates this simply and clearly in HTML view: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNj

Put in simple comparison, the output looks like this

```
body footnote #        footnote div footnote #
     1                          3
     2                          1
     3                          2
```

I believe this is a question of order processing, but after attempting to adjust it through `modes` and `priority` I have not been able to solve this. It seems to have to do with moving the `seg` element before giving it a number...

Many, many thanks in advance.

NB: the number for `seg/@corresp` and `date` can only ever appear once each per `<seg>` maximum; `note` can theoretically appear several times.

Comment: Are the textual footnotes in the right order, only the numbering is wrong?

Comment: The footnote numbers in the text body are in the right order, with the right number. But in the `div` the content of footnote #1 should be #3, #2 should be #1, and #3 should be #2. In short the footnote for `seg` is outputting first instead of last, where `seg` in fact encloses the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to correct the variable to

```
<xsl:variable name="footnote-sources" select="$fn-markers-added//tei:date[@type='deposition_date'] |                            
            $fn-markers-added//tei:note[@type='public'] | $fn-markers-added//tei:fn-marker"/>
```

as you no longer want to number the `seg`s but rather the `fn-marker`s they have been transformed to in the intermediary step.

Then you also need to adjust the template to

```
<!-- outputs each item to a <p> in footnote <div> -->
<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $footnote-sources]" mode="build_footnotes">
    <xsl:choose>    
    <xsl:when test="self::tei:date[@type='deposition_date']">
            <xsl:element name="p">
                <sup>
                    <xsl:number count="*[. intersect $footnote-sources]" format="1" level="any"/>
                </sup> this is the foo /date (that should be footnote #1)
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::tei:fn-marker">
            <xsl:element name="p">
                <sup>
                    <xsl:number count="*[. intersect $footnote-sources]" format="1" level="any"/>
                </sup> this is the foo seg/@corresp (that should be footnote #3)
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>  
        <xsl:when test="self::tei:note[@type='public']">
            <xsl:element name="p">
                <sup>
                    <xsl:number count="*[. intersect $footnote-sources]" format="1" level="any"/>
                </sup> this is the foo /note (that should be number footnote #2)
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

That ways https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNj/1 shows

```
1 this is the foo /date (that should be footnote #1)

2 this is the foo /note (that should be number footnote #2)

3 this is the foo seg/@corresp (that should be footnote #3)
```

obviously the explanation "this is the foo `seg/@corresp` is a bit misleading now as it is really a `fn-marker` placed earlier the transformation step.